# Python PyQt5 print multi-color to plaintextedit

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qplaintextedit

To make this easier. How would I print to a QPlainTextEdit the list

```py
['The', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'jumps', 'over', 'the', 'lazy', 'dog']
```

using a different color for each word?

Comment: I have provided enough code to make this understandable

Comment: Well, not for me since your explanation is confusing and I wanted to get it from your code.

Comment: The question is simply can I print color to a PlainTextEdit window. Everything else is just why and how.

Comment: That is what I am wanting to do. I want to print different words in the QPlainTextEdit with different colors. So instead of Stack(RED) Overflow(GREEN) it would be Key(RED) Value(RED), if this variable is missing. Else I will print everything green.

Comment: It will be printed like this key1:value1 \n key2:value2

Comment: I don't know what you are asking

Comment: I don't know how any of that has to do with this. To make this easier. How would I print to a QPlainTextEdit the list ['The', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'jumps', 'over', 'the', 'lazy', 'dog'] using a different color for each word?

Comment: Are the colors random? And if so, then the colors should not be repeated?

Comment: Lol. sure any color that does not matter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To change the color of the text you can use:

- QTextCharFormat:

```py
import random
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    names = ["The", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog"]

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit()
    w.show()

    # save format
    old_format = w.currentCharFormat()

    for name in names:
        color = QtGui.QColor(*random.sample(range(255), 3))

        color_format = w.currentCharFormat()
        color_format.setForeground(color)
        w.setCurrentCharFormat(color_format)
        w.insertPlainText(name + "\n")

    # restore format
    w.setCurrentCharFormat(old_format)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

- Html

```py
import random
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    names = ["The", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog"]

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit()
    w.show()

    for name in names:
        color = QtGui.QColor(*random.sample(range(255), 3))

        html = """<font color="{}"> {} </font>""".format(color.name(), name)
        w.appendHtml(html)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]